# PHP Pdo: Showing records out of database

Tags: php, pdo

I want to show all the records from the DB on my website, it's a PDO built website. I want it to show all the records so you can see what's in the DB.

[This is how my DB looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEJyj.png)

The connection is set up in a different document called config.php

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');

error_reporting(E_ALL & ~ E_DEPRECATED);
ini_set('display_errors', 'ON');

$CONFIG = array();
$CONFIG['root'] = '/home/tom/public_html';
$CONFIG['rootwebsite'] = '/home/tom/public_html';
$CONFIG['website'] = 'https://###';

$CONFIG['dbhost'] = 'localhost';
$CONFIG['dbuser'] = '####';
$CONFIG['dbpass'] = '####';
$CONFIG['dbdatabase'] = 'tom';
?>
```

This is the code I have in a php document and tried using. The problem is it won't show anything on my website (this is a different file than the file my website is):

```
<?php

class Forum {

    private $dbh; //dbh = database handler.

    public function __construct($database) {
        $this->dbh = $database;
    }

    public function getForum() {
        $getTopic = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM topics ORDER BY id DESC");
        $getTopic->execute();
        $topics = $getUTopic->fetchAll();
        foreach ($topics as $topic) {
            echo $topic['onderwerp'] . '<br />';
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: **enable error reporting!!** `$dbh->prepare` should be `$this->dbh->prepare`.. didnt look any further.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I have and that is not it

Comment: using `prepare()` is useless. Just execute the query. You are not binding anything

Comment: `$getUTopic` is not the statement you prepare.

Comment: I do that on the line after that? @Akintunde007

Comment: Did you change everything to $this->dbh? like Lawrence Cherone mentioned because in your updated code I only see it changed in the constructor but not in the getForum function.

Comment: Its defined but are you calling `Forum`? Please show where you initialize PDO and call the getForum method.

Comment: @NigelRen what do you mean? Can you explain?

Comment: Your prepare puts the result into `$getTopic`, but you fetchAll on `$getUTopic`.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I am not calling for `forum` anywhere but `$database = new Database($CONFIG['dbuser'] ,$CONFIG['dbpass'] ,$CONFIG['dbdatabase'], $CONFIG['dbhost']);` this is how the pdo is made

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the right `$connection` variable. It should be `$this->dbh`

```
$getTopic = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM topics ORDER BY id DESC");
```

Also you are mixing the variables after `execute()`. You should use easy to remember variables.

```
public function getForum() {
    try {
        $getTopic = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM topics ORDER BY id DESC");
        $getTopic->execute();
        $topics = $getTopic->fetchAll();
        foreach ($topics as $topic) {
            echo $topic['onderwerp'] . '<br />';
        }
    } catch (PDOException $pdoEx) {
        echo $pdoEx->getMessage();
        exit;
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
}
```

Also since you are not passing any variable to your query, there is no point of using `prepare()`. Just call `query()` instead.

For error reporting add,

`error_reporting(E_ALL); #place at the top of the script`

Also you should consider using a proper IDE like PHPstorm or Netbeans, as they would easily point out unsed variables

As suggested by [@adpro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1572834/adpro), here is a [link](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), to help with debugging

Comment: Plus one for the IDE suggestion - is there a general debugging php topic on here?  That would be nice to link to for questions like this.

Comment: If I change it like this it still wont show any errors or records on the website.

Comment: This article is linked in the help - [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @Tomishotttieee how do you establish PDO connection? also how do you call the function `getForum()`? Please add it to your question

Comment: The OP first needs to get [error reporting working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Comment: I am not calling the function `getForum`?and you can see my config file? or do you mean this? `$database = new Database($CONFIG['dbuser'] ,$CONFIG['dbpass'] ,$CONFIG['dbdatabase'], $CONFIG['dbhost']);`

Comment: you have to call the function `getForum()` ! then why have it in the first place?

Comment: @Akintunde007 how do i do that in this case?